# Typescript map types with different property names

Tags: angular, typescript

I use Angular 6 + TypeScript 2.7.2 and I have a component that need `ISelect[]` type:

```
export interface ISelect {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
```

So each time I call the component I need pass a `ISelect[]`. for example I have a `IProject[]` and I need to map it to `ISelect[]` In another example I have `IClient[]` and again I need map it to `ISelect[]`, here is `IProject`:

```
export interface IProject {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    code: string;
    clientId: number;
    status: number;
    level: number;
    masterKey: number;
    parentId?: number;
}
```

I need to map it like this pseudocode.

```
 myprojects: IProject[];
 myselect: ISelect[] = myprojects.Foreach.Map<ISelect>(id: id, title: name);
```

Or:

```
export interface IClient {
    code: number,
    fullname: string,
    streetNumber: string,
    streetName: string,
    postalCode: string,
    city: string,
    isActive: boolean
}
```

And I need this map:

```
myClients: IClient[];
myselect: ISelect[] = myClients.Foreach.Map<ISelect>(id: code, title: fullname);
```

How could I do this mapping. I prefer to avoid have a for loop inside my source array. but I could have different mappings each time I need to condvert. any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
myselect: ISelect[] = this.myprojects.map(p => { return <ISelect>{ id: p.id, title: p.name } });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write mapping method every time you have new class that can be converted to `ISelect`, you can write a generic converter method.

Here is one attempt wherein you have to specify keys that will map to `id` and 
`title` of `ISelect` interface.

```
  convert<T, TK extends keyof T>(arr: T[], idKey: TK, titleKey: TK) : any[] {
    return arr.map( item => {
      return { id: item[idKey], title: item[titleKey] };
    });
  }
```

And call it with either `IClient` or `IProject` - type script will do some type checking for you.

You can use something like this for array of `IClient`

```
let arrOfClients: IClient[] = [
  {
     code: 1, 
    fullname: 'test', 
    streetNumber: '12', 
    streetName: 'street', 
    postalCode: '12', 
    city: 'Bangalore', 
    isActive: true 
  }
];
let converted: ISelect[] = convert(arrOfClients, "code", "fullname");
```

Similarly, you can use something like this for array of `IProject`

```
let converted: ISelect[] = convert(arrOfProjects, "id", "name");
```

Comment: Great answer that actually shows us some relevant Typescript constructs. I like your use of `keyOf T` to get some strong typing on the field names to map.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) parameter to define your mapping in the function passed to `.map()`:

```
myselect: ISelect[] = myprojects.map(({ id, name: title }) => ({ id, title }));
```

This approach also works for `IClient` like this:

```
myselect: ISelect[] = myClients.map(({ code: id, fullname: title }) => ({ id, title }));
```