# Difficulty Mapping FusionAuth Errors to TypeScript due to changing nested object names

Tags: node.js, typescript, fusionauth

I am trying to map FusionAuth errors into Typescript interfaces for improved error handling. But I am running into problems.

An example error returned is the following nested object:

`{"statusCode":400,"exception":{"fieldErrors":{"email":[{"code":"[duplicate]email","message":"A User with email already exists."}]}}}`

And another error returned by FusionAuth is the following:

`{"statusCode":400,"exception":{"fieldErrors":{"password":[{"code":"[tooShort]password","message":"The [user.password] property is shorter than the minimum of [8] characters."}]}}}`

As you can see, exception.fieldErrors.XYZ is a different object name for each error.
I want to try and abstract the exception.fieldErrors.XYZ error into typescript classes, and create a method that iterates over the exception.fieldErrors.XYZ object, and pushes them into an array. Below are some TypeScript classes at an attempt of solving this.

```
export class ClientResponseError {
  statusCode: string;
  exception: Exception;
}


export interface ExceptionName {
  message: string;
}

export interface FieldErrors {
  fieldError: ExceptionName[];
}

export interface Exception {
  fieldErrors: FieldErrors;
}
```

and the following short snippet to test printing out the messages

```
error.exception.fieldErrors.fieldError.map(error => {
     console.log(error.message)
    })
```

The main error returned is the following
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`    
Any suggestions for dealing with this? The problem lies that exception.fieldErrors.XYZ is a different object name for each error, and I want to catch all errors. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a typescript dev, but would something like the answers suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406141/typescript-map-types-with-different-property-names work?

Comment: Thanks mooreds, I was able to get enough info from that thread to solve the problem.

Comment: please share your answer here, it'll help anyone else looking.